# Angularjs Not finding My html file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi i have been in the past view days try'n to figure out the problem of Angularjs UI not being able to find a templateUrl that i am passing it. As far as my understanding when giving a directory to a templateUrl value it is from the URL in the top search bar. When i pass the value in for the templateUrl it gives back an error 404 could not find the file. This drives me crazy because i did this exact thing in another project and it worked fine without any issues.

[![Folder Structure][1]][1]

[![Code][2]][2]

EDIT:
I have three different files that i have.

Index.php

```
<?php
    require_once("site/header.php");
?>

<!-- angular view which brings in the content-->
<div id="main" >
    <div class="{{pageClass}}" ui-view>

    </div>
</div>
<!-- end -->

<?php
    require_once("site/footer.php");
?>
```

Inside of my header.php i bring in angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="polycodeWebApp">
<head>
<title>Polycode</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PolycodeApp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/websiteAppController.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-309912-5']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript';    ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body class="" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding: 5px" ui-sref="home">
      <b><img style="height: 40px;" src="images/logo.svg"/>Polycode</b>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a ui-sref="features">Features</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="download">Download</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="learn">Learn</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref="community">Community</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

Now this is the page that gets loaded in and it brings a child view with it. This is the file that is giving me problems. It does not find my file intro.html

```
<?php
require_once("learn_header.php");

?>

<div class="{{pageClass}}" ui-view="lessons">

</div>

<?php

    require_once("learn_footer.php");
?>
```

and this is the content inside of intro.html.

```
<div class="page-header">
<h2>Introduction</h2>
```

Welcome to the Polycode learning section! This collection of articles will take you from setting up your first Polycode application all the way through most of its main features.

These articles are organized roughly in the order they should be read, but feel free to jump to any of the sections and read about a specific feature.

Example code is provided in both C++ and Lua, except for features where Lua bindings are not supported or a Lua-only feature is discussed.

This guide is designed as an overview of the main API features of Polycode, but only covers the basic methods and properties of the classes discussed. For a complete list of class methods and properties, see the generated documentation in the Polycode distribution or under **Help →API Reference** in the IDE.

The articles are under continuous development and may contain errors. If you would like to contribute an article or see an error that should be fixed or an opportunity for improvement, please fork the [Polycode website on github](https://github.com/ivansafrin/PolycodeSite) and submit a pull request.

Comment: Would be helpful to actually embed your code in the question itself instead of just posting an image.

Comment: not helping until you post the actual code HTML and JS.

Comment: is this because your paths are wrong? from js/polycode.app, defining a templateurl of features/index.php would be resolved as js/features/index.php unless there's some php quirk I dont know about.

Answer (score 0):

Define your angular controller in your html file if you haven't .

Comment: Sounds more like a comment and not an answer.

Comment: This isn't really correct since you don't need to define your angular controller in an html file when using angular ui router..

Comment: At the time of my answer, code wasn't posted. And often is the case you may have forgot to add a simple code. These always happens.